# How to make an Odoo addons(module) installation

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-8, python-packaging

How to make an Odoo addons(module) installation without manually copy and pasting the created module to addons_path directory.

Is it possible?

I searched possible solutions

1. Using pip to package and install Odoo addons
2. Using odoo-autodiscover

Does anyone already tried the above options? is there any easiest way?

Comment: Have you tried to put the path of the parent directory of your module in the addons_path parameter when you launch your server ?

Comment: I think he want something like upload the module by using a form in odoo? Am I right?

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET, yes, that is the usual setup/configuration, my goal is to find way how to something like automating it.

Comment: @Nope, that is not what i am aiming.